# C trouble with function calling with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm using a structure array to save data about specific person, and have 2 function which write out data. 3rd function (Wypisz) uses pointer to use specified one. The problem is when i try to compile it, error occurs in this function in both 'if clauses':

error: expected expression before 'struct'

```
struct Osoba
{    char imie[MAX], nazwisko[MAX];
    int rokurodzenia[N];
};

void WypiszWLinii(struct Osoba osoba[])
{    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("%c %c, %d\n", osoba[i].imie, osoba[i].nazwisko, osoba[i].rokurodzenia);
}
}
void WypiszJedenPoDrugim(struct Osoba osoba[])
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    printf("%c\n%c\n%d\n", osoba[i].imie, osoba[i].nazwisko,    osoba[i].rokurodzenia);
}
}
void Wypisz(void (*wskfun)(struct Osoba), int i)
{
    if(i=1)
{
    wskfun=WypiszJedenPoDrugim(struct Osoba osoba[]);
}
else if(i=0)
{
    wskfun=WypiszWLinii(struct Osoboa osoba[]);
}
else
{
    printf("Wybrano zla opcje w menu\n");
    return -1;
}
}
```

N and MAX is predefined variable with library inclusions

Comment: what line does the compiler say the error is on?

Comment: both lines with  'wskfun= ' expression

Comment: `wskfun=WypiszJedenPoDrugim;` I believe that would assign wskfun to the function pointer. You only include the parameter braces when you're calling the function and declaring it. Function pointers are expressed as just the method name.

Comment: it seems it has worked out well, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you have in the Wypisz function implementation is the assignement of pointer to a function to a wrong value.
Instead to :

```
wskfun=WypiszJedenPoDrugim(struct Osoba osoba[]);
```

or

```
wskfun=WypiszWLinii(struct Osoba osoba[]);
```

you have to get the pointer to that function and assing it to the variable:

```
wskfun = &WypiszJedenPoDrugim;
```

or

```
wskfun = &WypiszWLinii;
```

After that you could use the pointer to the function like:

```
wskfun("pointer to struct array");
```

Said that, to solve your problem the function must be changed like:

```html
void Wypisz(void(*wskfun)(struct Osoba[]), int i)
{
    if (i = 1)
    {
        wskfun = &WypiszJedenPoDrugim;
    }
    else if (i = 0)
    {
        wskfun = &WypiszWLinii;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wybrano zla opcje w menu\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```